# How to pass arguments to a function that's nested inside the Ipywidgets.interactive_output() function

Tags: callback, nested, data-visualization, dashboard, ipywidgets

Documented behavior:

```
a = widgets.IntSlider()
b = widgets.IntSlider()
c = widgets.IntSlider()
ui = widgets.HBox([a, b, c])
def f(a, b, c):
    print((a, b, c))
out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
display(ui, out)
```

Desired behaviour:
Widget > Value Assigned to Variable > Input in analysis > Compute > Plot

Problem: Nesting a compute_function will cause an error saying that df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 are not defined (not being fed into the outside function).
Alternately, I can try to feed df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 into the interact function "f" in this example. However, this will give me an error that inputs should be widgets.

```
a = widgets.IntSlider()
b = widgets.IntSlider()
c = widgets.IntSlider()
ui = widgets.HBox([a, b, c])
def f(a, b, c):
    df = compute_function(a, b, c, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
    plot = df.plot()
    display(plot)

out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
display(ui, out)
```

Perhaps the desired outcome described above is not a good approach. What is a better approach:

1. compute all possible permutations into a huge dataframe, which will
   be    passed into widgets.interactive_output() to filter the huge
   dataframe?
2. nest a computation function inside widgets.interactive_output() ?

Comment: Not sure why option two would be considered 'not good', could you explain why? The examples in the docs are always pretty trivial and not intended to demonstrate 'best practice'. If your `compute_function` takes a long time you could use a lru_cache decorator to avoid expensive recalculation.

Comment: Thank you @ac24 for your comment. I have added a problem statement above; I hope this helps diagnose the problem.

Comment: Where are your dataframes defined? Could you not put them in the global scope, so the references would work? I don't see why it won't work, can you add in a dummy dataframe as an example as perhaps I am misunderstanding the issue here.

Alternatively you can 'fix' arguments into an interact, so they don't try to get interpreted as widgets: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Fixing-arguments-using-fixed

Comment: Thank you, @ac24. Adding 'fixed(df1)' argument has solved the issue.